# How can I use this function based on an array to change a label displaying a total of that array in another class?

Tags: arrays, swift, function, uiviewcontroller, label

I have developed a small Swift code that displays somebody's total likes. So I have one code based on a while loop to add up the amount of likes into one total. Then, I created a function that displays a short phrase including the result of that loop. Now, in my view controller I want to run that display function on a label I have created to finally display the all time likes on the screen. However, I can't seem to understand how I should run the display function on the label and have it display without it being a result of me clicking a button first. Keep in mind, this is my second day of coding, with only prior experience in the basic syntax of Java.

Here is the first code

```
import UIKit

class likesObject: NSObject {
// This is where I created the loop to solve for the total amount of likes
func complimentsLikeTotal() -> Void {
    let monthlyLikes = [20, 15, 13, 32, 14, 38]
    var totalLikes = 0
    var runTotal = 0

    while runTotal < monthlyLikes.count {
        totalLikes += monthlyLikes[runTotal]
        print(totalLikes)
        runTotal += 1
    }

}
/*
 This is where I created the function to return how many all time likes there are in a phrase
 I want to use this function in the viewcontroller code on the label
 */
func display() -> String {
    return "\(complimentsLikeTotal) all time likes"
}

}
```

Here is the view controller code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var inputLikesLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Here is where I don't know what to do with display and how to link it with the label
    self.inputLikesLabel.text = display

}

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is `self.inputLikesLabel.text = display"` not updating the label text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably looking for something like this: (please make the class name start with capital as per convention)

```
var likesObject = LikesObject()
likesObject.complimentsLikeTotal()
let display = likesObject.display()
self.inputLikesLabel.text = display
```

I assume that the LikesObject class also has some global variables defined to hold the data.

P.s. in swift it is not necessary to explicitly state void return value, if you omit it the compiler implies void.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it isn't fully functioning. When I run it on the simulator, the screen displays: (function) all time likes. What should I do now?

Comment: That us because complimentsKikeTotal does not return anything (void). If you want to fix this change the return type to Int and return total likes or whichever the like number is.

Comment: It worked, I also found a small error that the computer did not pick up within the display function. I wrote \(complimentsLikeTotal) instead of \(complimentsLikeTotal()) which was the main error.

Comment: Great. Now you can pick the answer as correct so people see that the question has been answered. If you have other issues be sure to come back and create a new question.